# QuillJS with .net blazor maximum string length

Tags: .net, blazor, quill

Hello I'm building a website with a QuillJS (https://quilljs.com/) rich text editor. You can paste images there from clipboard. Basically I've followed this tutorial to integrate it: http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4364/Creating-A-Rich-Text-Editor-In-Blazor-Using-Quill.aspx

The problem arises when I try to insert an image too big or too complex (like too much colour). The program doesn't crash, but it just refuses to process the content(when pressed the save button). I've tested to see the maximum length of the string and it appears to be somewhere around 65300 characters.
QuillJS converts the images to Base64, which I would then store to the database.

Are there any alternatives to QuillJS? I've seen people suggesting blob, but I haven't seen it iterated in a rich text editor or something.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote that article.
Have you seen: [Uploading Images With The Blazor Rich Text Editor](http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4369/Uploading-Images-With-The-Blazor-Rich-Text-Editor.aspx)?
There I am simply inserting a link to the images not the actual image itself.

Comment: That's cool and all, but I NEED it to be pasted from clipboard